# text/template inside js-file?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to move this code from my **html**-file to a **js**-file, is there any smooth way to do this without having to put the HTML-code as a string?

```
<script type="text/template" id="template_test">
    <h4>Test</h4>
    <p>blablabla</p>
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: why would you put some html code ina javascript file?

Comment: @LordNeo Right now all my templates are placed in my only HTML-file while all the code for those templates are split among multiple JS-files. Having the HTML-code in the JS-files would make things much more structured

Comment: Javascript files are for JS code. You could put some html, but it will be in non-native way (as strings or objects). I would recommend to split the HTML file in smaller PHP files and then use the include option to stitch all together. Neither HTML or JS are template engines, PHP is (or was). The hard way would be to split the HTML into JS objects and then put them on the site, but i think it would be too much overload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the createElement function to create HTML elements however if you intend to move alot of code you should consider using a templeting engine.

```
// Create the <h4> element
var heading = document.createElement("h4"); 

// add the text    
heading.textContent = "TEST";

// Create the text node <p>       
var p = document.createTextNode("blablabla");  

//get the element to which you want to append the h4 and p
var container = document.getElementById("myID");

// Append h4 and p 
container.appendChild(heading);
container.appendChild(p);
```